# Symfony 3 Use 2 guards authenticator

Tags: symfony, authentication

I am using authentication with guard in my application. I have 2 different way to login with 2 distinct guard authenticator.
my security looks like this :

```
    firewalls:

    login:
        pattern: /(login|api.*)$
        anonymous: ~

    autolog:
        pattern: /(autolog.*)$
        anonymous: ~
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - app.autolog_authenticator

    main:
        logout:
            invalidate_session: true
            path: /%locale%/logout
            target: /%locale%/login

        guard:
            authenticators:
                - app.token_authenticator
```

The token_authenticator works perfectly. But when I use autolog, the user is perfectly log with the autolog_authenticator, but then it goes in the token_authenticator that refuse the connection.
How can I tell the application to only use the autolog_authenticator and dont go to the token_authenticator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find how I can do.
I just used the same context for each guard. I use it like this

```
firewalls:

login:
    pattern: /(login|api.*)$
    anonymous: ~

autolog:
    pattern: /(autolog.*)$
    context : primary_auth
    anonymous: ~
    guard:
        authenticators:
            - app.autolog_authenticator

main:
    context : primary_auth
    logout:
        invalidate_session: true
        path: /%locale%/logout
        target: /%locale%/login

    guard:
        authenticators:
            - app.token_authenticator
```

Answer (score 0):

this does not look optimal

```
pattern: /(login|api.*)$
```

try to protect your api area with token only

Have a look at this implementation example here https://github.com/knpuniversity/guard-presentation/blob/finished/app/config/security.yml

Another keyword you might need is `entrypoint` which defines, what authentication has a higher priority